# Building a 2D List

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Looking for a function that would do something akin to the following:

```
   (foo 3 2) => '( ( (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) )
                   ( (2 1) (2 2) (2 3) ) )
```

Would there be any built-in function in DrRacket that accomplishes that?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you want the function to do. How does the nested listing work for more than 2 arguments?

Answer (score 6):

The main tool that you want to use to get such things in Racket is the various [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html) loops.  Assuming that you want to create a list-based matrix structure, then this is one way to get it:

```
#lang racket
(define (foo x y)
  (for/list ([i y])
    (for/list ([j x])
      (list (add1 i) (add1 j)))))
```

And since people raised the more general question of how to make `foo` create a matrix of any dimension, here's a generalized version that works with any number of arguments, and still returns the same result when called as `(foo 3 2)`:

```
#lang racket
(define (foo . xs)
  (let loop ([xs (reverse xs)] [r '()])
    (if (null? xs)
      (reverse r)
      (for/list ([i (car xs)])
        (loop (cdr xs) (cons (add1 i) r))))))
```

(Note BTW that in both cases I went with a simple 0-based iteration, and used `add1` to get the numbers you want.  An alternative way would be to replace

```
(for/list ([i x]) ... (add1 i) ...)
```

with

```
(for/list ([i (in-range 1 (add1 x)]) ... i ...)
```

)

Comment: Note that the first code snippet could use `for*/list`.  Also, I think you mean `y`, not `x`, in your parenthetical remarks.

Comment: No, you cannot use `for*/list`, since that will generate a flat list of pairs, and the original question asked for a matrix like list-of-lists result.  And in the parenthetical comment I meant that the transformation could be done for any `x` and `i` meta variables -- I just didn't want to duplicate the whole thing redundantly.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
(define (foo-makey const max data)
  (let* ((i (length data))
         (newy (- max i))
         (newpair (cons const newy)))
    (if (= max i)
        data
        (foo-makey const max
                   (cons newpair data)))))

(define (foo-makex xmax ymax data)
  (let* ((i (length data))
         (newx (- xmax i)))        
    (if (= xmax i)
        data
        (foo-makex xmax ymax
                   (cons (foo-makey newx ymax '()) data)))))

(define (foo x y)
  (foo-makex y x '()))
```

Output:

```
> (foo 3 2)
'(((1 . 1) (1 . 2) (1 . 3)) ((2 . 1) (2 . 2) (2 . 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question as-is because I don't understand how the nested lists should work for >2 arguments. AFAIK there is no built-in function to do what you want.

To start you off, here is some code that generates output *without* nested lists. As an exercise try adjusting the code to do the nested listing. And see if there's a way you can make the code more efficient.

```
;;can take in any number of arguments
(define (permutations . nums)
  (foldl
   (lambda (current-num acc)
     (append-map
      (lambda (list-in-acc)
        (for/list ((i (build-list current-num (curry + 1))))
          (append list-in-acc (list i))))
      acc))
   (list (list))
   (reverse nums)))
```

Example 1:

```
> (permutations 3 2)
'((1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (2 1) (2 2) (2 3))
```

Example 2:

```
> (permutations 10)
'((1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10))
```

Example 3:

```
> (permutations 2 3 4)
'((1 1 1)
  (1 1 2)
  (1 2 1)
  (1 2 2)
  (1 3 1)
  (1 3 2)
  (2 1 1)
  (2 1 2)
  (2 2 1)
  (2 2 2)
  (2 3 1)
  (2 3 2)
  (3 1 1)
  (3 1 2)
  (3 2 1)
  (3 2 2)
  (3 3 1)
  (3 3 2)
  (4 1 1)
  (4 1 2)
  (4 2 1)
  (4 2 2)
  (4 3 1)
  (4 3 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

(define (build-2d row col)
   (build-list row (lambda(x) (build-list col (lambda(y) (list (+ x 1) (+ y 1))))))